# Receiving a bad handshake SSLError for a particular URL using requests.get in python.

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am having an issue with getting a particular URL response using requests that I need for web scraping. I have been able to get all other URLs to work except this one. My code:

```
import requests
u = "https://jobs.utc.com"
r = requests.get(u)
r
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)
```

Is there a reason why this URL is giving me trouble?

Comment: The server redirects to the HTTP (without S) version anyway. So you might just try HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the same error in my browser, coming from Cloudflare. It seems that this particular host simply has a problem, and you are not facing a particular Python or socket challenge.

[Cloudflare error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECcBr.png)